# requests_mock fixture with unittest library?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-requests, mocking, fixtures

I need to mock `requests` library, so figured to use `requests_mock` library for that. Though I wonder how can I create a fixture for my test class when using `unittest` library?

I can do this with `testtools`, like:

```
import testtools
from requests_mock.contrib import fixture

class MyTestCase(testtools.TestCase):
    TEST_URL = 'http://some-not-existing-url.com'

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        self.requests_mock = self.useFixture(fixture.Fixture())
        self.requests_mock.post(self.TEST_URL, status_code='200')

    def test_01_method(self):
        resp = requests.post(self.TEST_URL)
        self.assertEqual('200', resp.status_code)
```

Now `unittest` does not have `useFixture` method. Is there some equivalent in `unittest` lib? Or I need to use some different approach there?

Trying similar thing (without `useFixture`, crashes tests):

```
import unittest
from requests_mock.contrib import fixture

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    TEST_URL = 'http://some-not-existing-url.com'

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        self.requests_mock = fixture.Fixture()
        self.requests_mock.post(self.TEST_URL, status_code='200')

    def test_01_method(self):
        resp = requests.post(self.TEST_URL)
        self.assertEqual('200', resp.status_code)
```

Running with `unittest`, I get `[Errno -2] Name or service not known`, which clearly shows that mocking does not apply correctly.

P.S. I need `unittest` lib, because it is used in framework which I use. So I need to incorporate these unittests to align with that framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using a fixture, you can explicitly start the mock in `setUp` and stop it in `tearDown`.

For example:

```py
import unittest
import requests_mock
import requests

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    TEST_URL = 'http://some-not-existing-url.com'

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        self.requests_mock = requests_mock.Mocker()
        self.requests_mock.post(self.TEST_URL, status_code='200')
        self.requests_mock.start()

    def test_01_method(self):
        resp = requests.post(self.TEST_URL)
        self.assertEqual('200', resp.status_code)

    def tearDown(self):
        super().tearDown()
        self.requests_mock.stop()
```